# Проблема с ldap

Tags: python, ldap

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста решить проблему с подключением к AD:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM

def ldap_authentication(user_name, user_pwd):
    ldap_user_name = user_name
    ldap_user_pwd = user_pwd
    ldsp_server = "ldap://****:636"
    user = f'CN={ldap_user_name},DC=***,DC=com'
    server = Server(ldsp_server, get_info=ALL)
    connection = Connection(server,
                            user=user,
                            password=ldap_user_pwd, authentication=NTLM)
    if not connection.bind():
       result = f'Error: {connection.last_error}'
    else:
        result = 'Success'

    return result

ldap_authentication('DOMAIN\****', '*****')
```

В результате получаю ошибку:

```
[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему:

```
ldsp_server = "***.com:636"
...
server = Server(ldsp_server, get_info=ALL,use_ssl=True)
```